# Wie sagt man "He's really competitive" auf Deutsch?

Tags: phrase-request

Ich habe ein paar Deutsche gefragt, wie man den Ausdruck sagt, aber sie antworten dass er selten benutzt wird.  Sie sagen dass 'wetteifernd'  ungefähr das Wort ist, aber niemand sagt, "Er ist wetteifernd" über eine Persönlichkeit.

Ist das richtig?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sprachen unterscheiden sich z.T. darin, welche Konzepte häufig verwendet werden und was man noch dazu zählt. Z.B. wird auf Japanisch, wie übrigens in vielen Sprachen, traditionell blau und grün nicht unterschieden. Das hat dazu geführt, dass zumindest die älteren Ampeln in Japan in einem Farbton gehalten sind, den die meisten Europäer als eindeutig blau bezeichnen würden.

Wo man auf Englisch sagt "he is competitive", unterscheidet man auf Deutsch zwischen verschiedenen Arten, wie jemand *competitive* sein kann bzw. muss noch weitere Informationen hinzufügen. Andererseits kann es sein, dass die letztlich benutzte Formulierung nicht zwangsläufig *competitive* impliziert. Man kann das also nur dann sicher richtig übersetzen, wenn man den gesamten Kontext genau kennt.

Wenn z.B. englisch sprechende Schüler einen Mitschüler als *competitive* bezeichnen, würden deutsch sprechende Schüler wahrscheinlich gleich sagen: "Er ist ein Streber". Das Wort ist im Deutschen unhöflich, aber nicht ganz so unhöflich wie die englischen Übersetzungen.

Aus deutscher Sicht ist *competitive* ein seltsames Wort, das die eigene Einstellung zu dem beschriebenen Verhalten im Dunkeln lässt. Was ist er denn nun? Ist er ambitioniert (mit Eigeninitiative; positives Wort)? Ist er strebsam (fleißig einem vorgegebenen Pfad folgend; gerade noch positives Wort)? Ist er ehrgeizig (auf Erfolg ausgerichtet, wobei er evt. auch über Leichen geht; ambivalentes Wort)? Oder ist er womöglich geltungssüchtig (will immer als der Beste angesehen werden, ohne dafür etwas zu leisten; negatives Wort)?

Für einen deutschen Muttersprachler wirkt *competitive* also ungefähr so wie ein geschlechtsneutral formulierter Satz, der sich auf eine unbekannte konkrete Person bezieht. Man wartet immer auf die Auflösung, ob es denn nun ein Mann oder eine Frau ist.

Comment: Ich habe es nicht überlegt, dass es so viele Kontexte gibt.  Die andere hatten auch gute Antworten, aber ich möchte das Wort eigentlich meistens negativ benutzen, wie "A Know-It-All" für jemand der immer recht haben muss.  Ich glaube deine Erklärung für geltungssüchtig passt, oder?  Danke für alle die Bespiele.

Comment: Ein know-it-all ist auf Deutsch ein Besserwisser, Schlauberger oder Klugscheißer. Davon kann man auch Adjektive ableiten (besserwisserisch, klugscheißerisch), aber das ist dann schon ziemlich informell. Ich finde auch, dass das Adjektiv *geltungssüchtig* sehr gut dazu passt, auch wenn es natürlich Unterschiede gibt. (Man kann Geltungssucht auch anders als durch Besserwisserei ausleben, und Besserwisser sind auch nicht zwingend geltungssüchtig.)

Comment: "wird auf Japanisch ... blau und grün nicht unterschieden" - wenn ich mir https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCn_und_Blau_in_verschiedenen_Sprachen#Japanisch durchlese, kommt mir das mindestens arg verkürzt vor. Trotzdem eine erhellende Antwort.

Comment: @Matthias: Ja, das ist in der Tat stark verkürzt. Ursprünglich wollte ich eigentlich was über den extrem spannenden Farbgebrauch bei Homer schreiben, aber das hätte ich gar nicht angemessen kürzen können. Jedenfalls gibt es in der linguistischen Literatur eine Beschreibung davon, in welcher Reihenfolge Sprachen neue Farbwörter annehmen und dadurch Farben neu unterscheiden. Die blau/grün-Unterscheidung ist die letzte der Grundfarben-Unterscheidungen. Danach kommen dann solche Farben wie z.B. orange, das es im Deutschen lange nicht gab. (Deshalb heute noch *gelbe* Rübe.)

Answer (score 4):

Was hat denn deine sonstige Recherche bisher ergeben?

Wetteifernd ist ein schönes Wort, wird umgangssprachlich aber [nicht besonders häufig gebraucht](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wetteifern).
Ich sehe beim englischen Wort competitive zwei Bedeutungsfelder.

Erstens: der Charakterzug, in Dingen besser sein zu wollen als andere Menschen. Dazu passen wetteifernd, streitbar, kämpferisch, geltungssüchtig, ausgeprägtes Konkurrenzdenken zeigend, rivalisierend.

Zweitens: etwas mit dem Ziel des Wettbewerbs betreibend, z.B. beruflich oder im Sport. In dem Zusammenhang fallen mir die Worte leistungs- oder wettbewerbsorientiert und kompetitiv ein.

Comment: wieso professionell?

Comment: Wegen der Bedeutung wettbewerblich von competitive. Vgl. http://dwds.de/?qu=professionell: „Eine Tätigkeit beruflich ausübend“ / Bsp: „ein professioneller Sportler (Berufssportler)“.
Sagt jemand “He’s a competitive fencer”, wäre eine Übersetzungsmöglichkeit m.A.n. „Er ist professioneller Fechter“.

Comment: Nja, nicht unbedingt. Es gibt auch Amateurwettkämpfe auf (je nach Sportart) sehr hohem Niveau.

Comment: Ja, ist mir beim Schreiben auch aufgefallen. Ich ändere meine Antwort noch ab, allerdings nicht jetzt sofort.

Answer (score 2):

Wahrscheinlich ist „wetteifernd“ schon eine gute, direkte Übersetzung. Trotzdem klingt es ungewöhnlich, und je nach Kontext würde man es auf Deutsch eher anders ausdrücken.

Im Sinne von »nimmt seine Position kritisch im Wetteifern der Konkurrenten ein«:

> Er ist wirklich konkurrenzfähig.

Im Sinne von »fasst sich gut in den Diskurs der Mitbewerber ein«:

> Er ist wirklich wettbewerbsfähig.

Im Sinne von »sticht andere Konkurrenten rasch aus«:

> Er ist ein echter Karrierist.

Tüchtigkeit lobend, umgangssprachlich:

> Er ist echt ehrgeizig.

Fleiß lobend, etwas gehobener:

> Er ist wahrlich ambitioniert.

Etymologisch steht “competitive” eher der Zielstrebigkeit, dem Strebsamen nahe statt dem Wettbewerb und der Konkurrenz.

Comment: _Seine Position kritisch einnehmen_, _sich in den Diskurs einfassen_: Was soll das heißen?

Comment: **a)** Die eigene Haltung argumentativ begründen und auch gegen Kritik verteidigen (und halten) können. **b)** Sich selbst (trotz des eigenen Standpunktes) gut in Konversationen eingliedern und (gegnerische) Argumentationen aufnehmen und geschickt retournieren können.

Comment: "Etymologisch steht “competitive” eher der Zielstrebigkeit, dem Strebsamen nahe statt dem Wettbewerb und der Konkurrenz." - das mag ja sein, aber durch den inzwischen im Englischen vollzogenen Bedeutungswandel vieler (aller?) Wörter mit demselben Wortstamm impliziert "competitive" in der heutigen Verwendung wohl eher praktisch unweigerlich einen starken bis vorwiegenden Wettbewerbsgedanken.

Comment: Natürlich, daher die wettbewerbsbezogenen Beispielübersetzungen. Herkunft ist trotzdem immer einen Blick wert.